# Defaults values in record constructors

Tags: clojure

I'm not quite understanding what's wrong about

```
(defrecord Person [name age])

(defn make-person [& opts]
  (let [defaults {:age 18}]
    (map->Person (merge defaults opts))))

(make-person {:name "Jim"})
=> ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry  clojure.lang.APersistentMap.cons (APersistentMap.java:42)
```

If I do:
    (map->Person (merge {:age 18} {:name "Jim"}))

I can also get the `make-person` function working with a non optional argument.

```
(defn make-person [opts]      
  (let [defaults {:age 18}]
    (map->Person (merge defaults opts))))
```

The solution I've settled on for what I want to do works like:

```
(defn make-person
  ([opts] (map->Person (merge {:age 18} opts)))
  ([] (map->Person {:age 18})))
```

So I guess I'm asking, what does `&` really do when destructuring function arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `& opts` returns a sequence, which is problematic if you pass a map in.

You probably want to destructure the sequence something like:

```
(defn make-person [& [opts]]
   (map->Person (merge {:age 18} opts))
```

Which lets you do `(make-person)` or `(make-person {:opt1 "foo" :opt2 "bar"})`

you could take advantage of the special syntax to allow keyword args:

```
(defn make-person [ & {:as opts} ]
   (map->Person (merge {:age 18} opts))
```

Allowing you to do `(make-person :opt1 "foo" :opt2 "bar")` but in my experience that makes calling `make-person` difficult if you want to do the merging outside the call (which you will one day) (i.e if you want `(make-person (merge some-opts some-other-opts)`